# Embedding dynamic row at the end of the resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a simple query that is returning two columns `ProjectName` and `Amount`. What I need is a dynamic row as the last most row having `Grand Total` and its in figure.

```
Project       GRN Value
Prj 1           100000
Prj 2           200000
Prj 3           400000
------------------------
Grand Total     700000
```

`Grand Total` should be a dynamic row embedded automatically at the end having the sum of `GRN` values.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need WITH ROLLUP after the GROUP BY

```
SELECT     Project,
           SUM(Value)
FROM       Table
GROUP BY   Project
WITH ROLLUP
```

[Check here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: `This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. ` I suggest to use `group by rollup`.

Comment: @RomanPekar I didn't really know that. Is there something equivalent?

Comment: take a look at my answer - it's group by rollup()

Comment: @RomanPekar I checked your solution but it needs a compatibility level of 100 or higher. So even though you might have SQL Server 2008 as stated, it is not the only condition that should be met. So if you have a compatibility of lower than 100 then it won't work. I guess these are both good solutions depening on your setup.

Answer (score 3):

To get grand total row you can use [group by rollup(Project)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx), to rename project in this grand total row use [grouping()](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms178544.aspx):

```
select
    case
        when grouping(Project) = 1 then 'Grand Total'
        else Project
    end as Project,
    sum([GRN Value]) as [GRN Value]
from Table1
group by rollup(Project)
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: +1 For a nice alternative and probably better solution, but keep in mind it needs a compatibility level of 100 or higher to use this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve this with a simple `UNION` so a SQL statement to calculate the `SUM` is appended to your result set:

```
SELECT Project, GRN_Value 
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand Total', SUM(GRN_Value)
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

Altenately you can use the `ROLLUP` function as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/09/21/aggregation-with-rollup.aspx).

Comment: With no guarantee that that row will appear at "the end" since you haven't an `ORDER BY` and there's no guarantee of the order in which rows will be returned from a `UNION ALL` without one.